# ArrayList clearing issue

Tags: java, android, arraylist, smsmanager

I'm creating an android app that sends sms. I actually have issues with the `ArrayList` containing the `PendingIntents` (`SentPenIntents` and `DelPenIntents`), which contains the succes or fail of the sending operation.

```
    private Runnable seekSms = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(phoneHasID) {
                try { 

                        ArrayList<PendingIntent> SentPenIntents = new ArrayList<>();
                        ArrayList<PendingIntent> DelPenIntents = new ArrayList<>();                      
                        String SENT_SMS_FLAG = "SENT_SMS";
                        String DELIVER_SMS_FLAG = "DELIVER_SMS";

                        Intent sentIn = new Intent(SENT_SMS_FLAG);
                        PendingIntent sentPIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),0,sentIn,0);

                        Intent deliverIn = new Intent(DELIVER_SMS_FLAG);
                        PendingIntent deliverPIn = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(),0,deliverIn,0);

                        BroadcastReceiver sentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                            @Override public void onReceive(Context c, Intent in) {
                                switch(getResultCode()){
                                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                        System.out.println("successfully sent !!");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        System.out.println("sending failed !!");
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        BroadcastReceiver deliverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                            @Override public void onReceive(Context c, Intent in) {
                                System.out.println("message received !!");

                            }
                        };
                        registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT_SMS_FLAG));
                        registerReceiver(deliverReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVER_SMS_FLAG));

                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        ArrayList<String> smsParts = smsManager.divideMessage(sms);


                        for (int i=0; i < smsParts.size(); i++){
                            SentPenIntents.add(i, sentPIn);
                            DelPenIntents.add(i, deliverPIn);
                        }

                        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(numero, null, smsParts, SentPenIntents, DelPenIntents);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pauseSms.postDelayed(seekSms, delayCT * 1000);
    }
};
```

It all works, the first time : in my console, i get, for a 3 sms-long message :

```
09-29 15:57:56.137  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 15:57:56.652  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 15:57:57.051  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 15:57:58.753  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 15:57:59.673  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 15:58:16.272  15781-15781/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
```

when the app comes to the sending of the second message, i get 3 more output messages for each list :

```
09-29 16:03:47.603  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:03:47.604  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:03:48.028  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:03:48.028  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:03:51.093  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 16:03:51.095  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 16:03:51.310  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 16:03:51.310  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 16:04:03.299  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:04:03.299  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ successfully sent !!
09-29 16:04:05.744  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
09-29 16:04:05.744  16011-16011/? I/System.out﹕ message received !!
```

and so on, the list stacks. I might have a problem clearing my `ArrayList` but i cant find out what it is.

Comment: SentPenIntents and  DelPenIntents you using in this method only or anywhre else where you clear your arraylist

Comment: I use them only in this method. I tried  SentPenIntents.clear(); but it didnt work

Comment: where you clearing that

Comment: juste after the "smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(numero, null, smsParts, SentPenIntents, DelPenIntents);"

Comment: you are registering new receivers all the time, but never unregistering them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never removing stuff from your lists. This is why it is stacking.

Try and remove intents when you receive a delivery confirmation.

**EDIT**
After further reviewing your code, I saw that you are registering the receivers each time you call your method. This leads to multiple receivers intercepting the events and printing the message only once. Try register them only once and see what happens.

You can easily test this by calling `unregisterReceiver` at the end of your method.

Comment: I tried to use " SentPenIntents.remove(this);" when i receive it, but it didnt work either

Comment: When part of the message is delivered, you will get the corresponding intent from `DelPenIntents `. You were trying to remove from the `SentPenIntent` which has no way of working. You need to be able to attach info in the confirmation intent to be able to identify the corresponding send intent. I found additional problems in your code. Please, check the edit to my answer

Comment: I'm a beginner in java and i have no clue of how to do this.. Could you get me on the way to identify the corresponding sent intent please ?

Comment: Try removing the multiple receivers first and check if you have the same problem again. Maybe it won't be even necessary to clean the lists.

Comment: What do you mean with "the multiple receivers" ?

Comment: Read my edit. You are registering broadcast receivers every time you call the method and they stay registered. All registered receivers intercept the sms intents and print messages, hence you duplicates. Deal with this problem and I think you will be OK